# WhatsApp images in photos

Tags: whatsapp, micro-sd

Hello I have Lumia 730.... First I had 8 GB micro SD card and all my data including images ,songs etc were in it.i installed several apps like WhatsApp Facebook etc on my phone memory and my phone were detecting all the photos inside the photos app which is given from windows... Even there was a separate album named"WhatsApp"inside that photos app..... But then I changed my micro SD from 8 GB to 32 GB.. And I transfer all my old micro SD data to the new micro SD... But the problem is now my p phone is not showing separate WhatsApp album.. Infact it is not even showing photos in"photos" app... What should I do...

Comment: Did you tried transfer only the photos to the new Whatsapp's folder? I mean, don't copy the entire folder, just the contents.

Comment: WhatsApp photos are in the WhatsApp folder... But they are not visible as separate WhatsApp album in photos in built app.. Probably I have mentioned in the question itself.

Comment: Same Problem with my Lumia 525, where i replaced a 4gb card with Samsung 16gb card

Answer (score 1):

Try a soft reset, then wait for the photos app to sync all of your pictures. I had the same trouble when I switched my phone off for couple of hours, it's now working fine.

Also, when you change SD cards always tap on safely remove the SD card.

Answer (score 1):

Solution:

1. Connect your phone to your PC via USB
2. Go to "SD card\Pictures"
3. Select the WhatsApp folder and rename it to WhatsApp1 or WhatsApp2 or whatever you want
4. Now open WhatsApp on your phone and download any picture from there
5. Now check your Photos app, a WhatsApp folder is created and the picture you downloaded will show up there
6. Now go to the folder you renamed earlier and copy all its contents to this new WhatsApp folder